# Android 7.0 скрыть уведомление после вызова onTaskRemoved

Tags: android, android-sdk

Привет! 
Обнаружил на Lenovo K6 возможность убивать приложения целиком свайпом в списке запущенных приложений.
При этом если сервис был запущен в режиме foreground через секунду после завершения приложения снова появляется уведомление и никаким образом оно не убирается из панели уведомлений.
При этом метод onDestroy у сервиса не вызывается и соответственно код, который корректно уничтожает уведомление не вызывается.

Вызов методов NotificationManager'a внутри onTaskRemoved ни к чему не приводит - уведомление остаётся.

Порекомендуете что-нибудь?
Сервис запущен в режиме foreground из-за того, что там идёт обмен по bluetooth, сбор координат и запись в БД.

Comment: Уведомление появляется не просто так - foreground-сервис после смахивания перезапускается и работает. Если Вам это не нужно - попробуйте останавливать сервис в `onTaskRemoved`.

Comment: Как оказалось сервис и правда пересоздаётся, но при этом вызывается только метод onCreate у сервиса и НЕ вызывается метод onStartCommand(null). Интересно, это штатная ситуация?

Comment: Скорее всего дело в значении, которое Вы возвращаете в `onStartCommand` (`return START_NOT_STICKY`, наверное?).

Comment: Нет, там наоборот START_STICKY и пересоздание сервиса и правда есть, но без вызова метода onStartCommand(null)